# php to javascript var initlisation

Tags: javascript

I have a var in javascript initialized by php, if I look in the console I can see that var and the value given. Can that value be hidden from console view ?

Thanks
In javascript

```
var v= <?php echo $Var_123;?>;
```

In `console v=123;`

Comment: No. I'm assuming this is some kind of sensitive data. If this is the case, **do not ever send it to the client**. Someone could always just view the source of your javascript file and get the value.

Comment: Unless you’re very specifically concerned about this being a global, no. JavaScript runs on the client side and is entirely visible during every step of execution to the user.

Comment: Thanks, so stupid question how do you requery sql with ajax call without converting php varible into javascript var

Comment: You can’t do that either, except by “hiding” the variable (in PHP). Maybe give each value a random key, stored in a database and looked up when you want to use it again. How to best do that really depends on your specific situation, though.

Comment: Thanks back to the drawing board :(